# Asymptotic expressions for number of $k$-prime products $<n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

Recently, I was able to prove on my own using the Prime Number Theorem and integration, that the number of semiprimes (product of two primes) till $n$, say $\pi_2(n)$, satisfies the asymptotic expression:
$$\pi_2(n) \sim \frac{n \ln{\ln{n}}}{\ln{n}}$$

After searching for similar results online, I found that if the number of numbers $<n$ which are the product of $k$ primes is defined as $\pi_k(n)$, then:
$$\pi_k(n) \sim \frac{n(\ln{\ln{n}})^{k-1}}{\ln{n} (k-1)!}$$

But I also saw that these asymptotic expressions are poor approximations for small $n$ and that these approximations become better very slowly. I want to ask whether the following is true or not:
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \bigg(\frac{e^{2^k}(\ln{\ln{e^{2^k}}})^{k-1}}{\ln{e^{2^k}} (k-1)!} \cdot \frac{1}{\pi_k(e^{2^k})}\bigg)=1$$

I assume this will be true since the function $f(k)=e^{2^k}$ grows really fast, satisfying:
$$f(k+1)=f(k)^2$$
and I want to know whether this growth rate is fast enough to make up for the slow change in accuracy of approximation that $\pi_k(n)$ gives. How do I prove this?

In general, what should the order of a function $g(k)$ be, so that:
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \bigg(\frac{g(k)(\ln{\ln{g(k)}})^{k-1}}{\ln{g(k)} (k-1)!} \cdot \frac{1}{\pi_k(g(k))}\bigg)=1$$

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: It turns out that this isn't true. We have:
$$\pi_k(n) = \frac{n(\ln{\ln{n}})^{k-1}}{\ln{n} (k-1)!}+O\bigg(\frac{n(\ln{\ln{n}})^{k-2}}{\ln{n}}\bigg)$$

The error term is really large and greater than the main term when $n=e^{2^k}$, disproving the claim. I need: $$g(x)>O\bigg(e^{e^{(k-1)!}}\bigg)$$ for the result to hold true.

Is there any result that adds more terms to the asymptotic expression for $\pi_k(n)$ such that the error term becomes smaller? (Preferably small enough so that the asymptotic expression will be a very good approximation for numbers of the order $e^{2^k}$.)

Comment: Note that this formula is the same if you count prime factors with or without multiplicity. It also represent $\rho_k(n)$ and $\sigma_k(n)$ and probably some other functions. Also check this post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35927/asymptotic-density-of-k-almost-primes if you have not

Comment: Compare $(-\log (s-1))^k$, $(\log \zeta(s))^k, P(s)^k,k!\sum_{\omega(n)=k} n^{-s}$

Comment: @reuns I am not aware of how to do so. If you do, could you post a complete answer?